# hosting website with video and audio conversion

Tags: web-hosting, video, looking-for-hosting, web-applications, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I have created a website with audio and video conversion online and providing the output file via email or instant download. I want to know which kind of hosting. server will work fine in my scenario. The video upload size is limited to 50mb per video and audio size is limited by 15Mb. After every two hours the completed video will be deleted, to ensure storage capacity. Please let me know web host server, which can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you look for a VPS or Dedicated server as opposed to "standard" shared hosting in this instance.

Many shared hosting companies would probably kill off any long-running scripts after a given period of time (and video/audio conversion will certainly fall into this category!), however with a VPS, it's all down to you to manage.

You can get low-end VPS (512M ram/25G disk space) for around $5 USD a month, however I'd check out the bandwidth allowance that you get (remember, all those uploads and downloads will cost you a lot if you exceed you bandwidth limits) and make sure that you've got quite a bit of RAM in the server (at least 1G for this kind of task in my opinion).